# Kestrel not listening in xUnit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit.net, kestrel-http-server

I'm using this custom server for unit-testing where I initialize it with `MyStarup` that loads a single middleware that I need for testing.

This has worked before with net47 and it stopped after I switched the project to .net-core. It now gives me this very helpful exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:30001

I create it from a `IClassFixture` with a factory method and call it with a `HttpClient` that I also create with a factory method and get it from the same fixture.

```
public class MyServer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWebHost _host;        

    public MyServer(string url) // <-- http://localhost:30001
    {
        _host =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls(url)                    
                .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
                .Build();

        Task = _host.StartAsync(); // <-- tried RunAsync too, no difference
    }

    public Task Task { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I make it work again?

I read this [Why Kestrel doesn't listen at specified port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895258/why-kestrel-doesnt-listen-at-specified-port)
 but it doesn't help solve it. I cannot run it as a console and it was working before. Why has it stopped after switching to .net-core?

Comment: Why not use test server for this integration test

Comment: @Nkosi I like to have everything under control. If they made it work then there has to be a way :-]

Comment: In .NET Core there is a WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> class available for the purpose of creating application host. It could be an alternate solution for your issue. It is also a recommended way to create a host for integration testing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  You need to use a custom configuration to specify the `urls` value for `Kestrel`, otherwise it's using some *random* (?) or default port `5001`. I didn't want to use `hosting.json` so I used the `InMemoryCollection`

```
    public MyServer(string url)
    {
        var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["urls"] = url
                })
                .Build();

        _host =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                //.UseUrls(url) // <-- cannot use this, seems to be deprecated
                //.Configure(app => { app.UsePathBase(url); }) // <-- does not work
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
                .Build();

        Task = _host.StartAsync();
    }
```